# Do I need intall nvidia driver on ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I have Dell latitude E6430 which include a nvidia nvs something 1GB, so is it necessarily to install a driver for it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are happy with the resolution and performance as is, you need do nothing. You may find you get higher resolution or better performance by installing a manufacturers driver.

If you would like to try this, run additional drivers and see if one pops up for your card.